# Select a browser, with webdriver and Visual Studio, from outside the code, in order to launch a night build with all browsers using the same code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, browser, build, tfs, webdriver

I am trying to implement a test suite using WebDriver and TFS.

The test suite consists of 100 tests that need to be launched every night in different browsers (Chrome, FF and IE9). This means that the same 100 tests will run first in IE, then  in FF, and then in Chrome.

These tests will be launched with a TFS build, triggered by time.

Normally, I would define the browser driver in `[TestInitialize]`, but if I define one of the browsers there, I can only launch 100 tests with that browser.

I am thinking of using three different builds of the same project. The three builds would be associated with the same code. So I have to define a variable outside the code, then pass that information to the code, and in the code do a switch and select the browser.

I have been trying to define that variable in testSettings.local, without success. And I have been trying to introduce that variable using the SetupScript of testSettings.Local, also without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) and some plugins like [Selenium plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin). Multiple machines, browsers and whatever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot speak to doing things in C#, however Java is similar enough that from the examples below you should be able to get an idea of how to go about what you need to do.

I have a browser class which looks like this:

```
public class Browser 
{
 public WebDriver getDriver(String driverName)
{
    WebDriver driver = null;
    if(driverName == "firefox")
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    else if(driverName == "chrome")
    {
        File chromeFile = new File ("C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeFile.getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    else if(driverName == "ie")
    {
        File ieFile = new File("C:/webdrivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", ieFile.getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }
    else if(driverName == "iOS")
    {
        try 
        {
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new   URL("http://localhost:3001/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.ipad());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    return driver;

}
}
```

Then I have one method which calls the browser class. Then my test methods determine which browser I am going to use so it would look something like this:

```
public class EditMedications_Cancel 
{
Browser browser = new Browser();
Random rand = new Random();
HighlightElement highlight = new HighlightElement();
WebDriver driver;

private void cancelButton(String driverName)
{
    int min = 1; //minimum random row
    int max = 5; //maximum random row
    driver = browser.getDriver(driverName); //get the Browser
    int rowNum = (rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min); //Random row
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

    //Open Browser, navigate to Patient Facing
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://someIP.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //Get a random row from the table and click it
    WebElement randomRow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum+"]/td"));
    randomRow.click();

    //Get Settings button and Click it
    int rowNum2 = (rowNum + 1);
    WebElement medicationName1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum2+"]/td/div/article/section/ul/li/h1"));
    WebElement dosage1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum2+"]/td/div/article/section/ul/li[2]/h3"));
    WebElement howMuch1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum2+"]/td/div/article/section/ul/li[3]/h3")); 
    WebElement reason1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum2+"]/td/div/article/section/ul/li[4]/p"));
    WebElement settingsBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum2+"]/td/div/article/aside/div/button"));
    String medicationNameBefore = medicationName1.getText();
    String dosageBefore = dosage1.getText();
    String howMuchBefore = howMuch1.getText();
    String reasonBefore = reason1.getText();

    settingsBtn.click();

    //Click Edit Button
    WebElement editBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum2+"]/td/div/article/aside/div/ul/li/a"));
    editBtn.click();

    //Make Changes and click Cancel
    WebElement medicationName2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum2+"]/td/div/article/section/form/fieldset/h1"));
    Select dosage2 = new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum2+"]/td/div/article/section/form/fieldset/label/select")));
    WebElement howMuch2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum2+"]/td/div/article/section/form/fieldset/label[2]/input"));
    WebElement reason2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum2+"]/td/div/article/section/form/fieldset/label[4]/input"));
    medicationName2.sendKeys("TEST TEST TEST");
    dosage2.selectByIndex(2);
    howMuch2.sendKeys("TEST TEST TEST");
    reason2.sendKeys("TEST TEST TEST");
    WebElement  cancelBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum2+"]/td/div/article/section/form/fieldset/div/button[2]"));
    cancelBtn.click();

    WebElement medicationName3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum2+"]/td/div/article/section/ul/li/h1"));
    WebElement dosage3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum2+"]/td/div/article/section/ul/li[2]/h3"));
    WebElement howMuch3= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum2+"]/td/div/article/section/ul/li[3]/h3")); 
    WebElement reason3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum2+"]/td/div/article/section/ul/li[4]/p"));
    String medicationNameAfter = medicationName3.getText();
    String dosageAfter = dosage3.getText();
    String howMuchAfter = howMuch3.getText();
    String reasonAfter = reason3.getText();
    Assert.assertEquals(medicationNameBefore, medicationNameAfter);
    Assert.assertEquals(dosageBefore, dosageAfter);
    Assert.assertEquals(howMuchBefore, howMuchAfter);
    Assert.assertEquals(reasonBefore, reasonAfter);
}

@Test(groups = {"functionalTests.FF"})
public void test_cancelButton_FF()
{
    cancelButton("firefox");
}
@Test(groups = {"functionalTests.iOS"})
public void test_cancelButton_iOS()
{
    cancelButton("iOS");
}
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void tearDown()
{
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

My XML file which launches the tests looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
<test name="Test">
  <groups>
  <run>
  <include name="functionalTests.FF"/>
  <exclude name="functionalTests.iOS"/>
  </run>
</groups>
  <classes>
  <class name="ui_Tests.AddPrescription" />
  <class name="ui_Tests.ClickAddMedication"/>
  <class name="ui_Tests.EditMedications_ValidateItems"/>
  <class name="ui_Tests.EditMedications_MedicationNameReadOnly"/>
  <class name="ui_Tests.EditMedications_EditStrengthForm"/>
  <class name="ui_Tests.EditMedications_HowMuch"/>
  <class name="ui_Tests.EditMedications_HowOften"/>
  <class name="ui_Tests.EditMedications_Reason"/>
  <class name="ui_Tests.EditMedications_Cancel"/>
  <class name="ui_Tests.ExpandCollapseView"/>
  </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
  </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

So with the include/exclude I can tell it which browsers to run the tests on.

Comment: You can use `Switch Case` instead of using `If-Else` in the Browser class. Because it will improve the performance.

Comment: Why are you getting the `File` only to get the `getAbsolutePath()` on the next line?

Comment: @AlexOkrushko Where are you referring?

Comment: `File chromeFile = new File ("C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeFile.getAbsolutePath());`. Why not to do `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe");` without getting the file first?

Comment: @AlexOkrushko I was simply following a suggestion of someone here on stackoverflow. Thanks for the suggestion, I will go ahead and fix that.

Comment: I see. It's always better to understand what the code means/does before simple "copy-paste". ;)

Comment: @AlexOkrushko I completely agree. I have been very much OJT learning Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your problem you may go with the `Selenium Grid and TestNG`. It is used to distribute and paralleling the tests in same machine with same browser, same machine with different browser and vice versa. You don't need to duplicate your build three times you can configure your browser details in the TestNG XML file as a using `Data Provider` concept.

For More info about [How to use Grid](http://blog.varunin.com/2011/10/selenium-grid-with-webdriver.html)